# Gauss Siedel iterative solver using OpenMP does not converge

Tags: fortran, openmp

I want to write a Gauss Siedel iterative solver using OpenMP. My solver does not converge to the correct result, and I could not figure it out why.

The governing equation is a steady-state heat equation: `del^2(T)=S`, where `S` is the heat source function. `S=-35*pi/2*cos(pi*x/2)*cos(3*pi*y/2)*cos(5*pi*z/2)`

I implement the OpenMP inside the dowhile loop since it does not let me start parallel form a do while loop. Is there any way to change the do while loop to a do loop?

The result converges without parallel computing, but after adding the openmp, then it does not converge anymore.

Here is my code:

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
    PROGRAM GAUSS_MP
        USE omp_lib
        IMPLICIT NONE

        REAL*8, DIMENSION(:,:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: S, T
        REAL*8 :: X, Y, Z
        REAL*8, PARAMETER :: PI=2*ASIN(1.0)
        REAL*8 :: DX                     ! STEP SIZE DX=DY=DZ
        REAL*8, PARAMETER :: TOL=1.0E-5  ! TOLERANCE 
        REAL*8 :: DUMAX
        REAL*8 :: T_OLD
        REAL*8 :: T1,T2

        INTEGER, PARAMETER :: N=100        ! GRID NUMBER, START FROM 1
        INTEGER, PARAMETER :: ITERMAX=1E5   ! MAXIMUM ITERATION
        INTEGER :: I, J, ITER, K
        INTEGER :: POINT_NUM
        INTEGER, PARAMETER :: NUM_THREADS=32
    !    INTEGER :: A

        ! INITIALIZE OPENMP THREADS
        CALL OMP_SET_NUM_THREADS(NUM_THREADS)


        ! COMPUTE STEP SIZE
        DX=2.0/REAL(N-1, KIND=8)  
    !    PRINT *, "DX=", DX
        
        ! INITIALIZE THE T ARRAYS AND S(I)
        ALLOCATE(S(N,N,N), T(N,N,N))
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````            
        ! INITIAL GUESS
        T=1.0
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````            
        ! BOUNDARY CONDITION
        T(1,:,:)=0.0; T(N,:,:)=0.0; T(:,:,1)=0.0; T(:,:,N)=0.0;
        T(:,1,:)=0.0; T(:,N,:)=0.0;
        
        X=0.0D0 ! COORDINATES
        Y=0.0D0

        S=0.0D0 ! SOURCE
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````            
        ! SOURCE MATRIX
        !$OMP PARALLEL DO PRIVATE(I,J,K)
         DO K=2,N-1
            Z=-1.0+(K-1)*DX
            DO I=2,N-1
                Y=-1.0+(I-1)*DX
                DO J=2,N-1
                    X=-1.0+(J-1)*DX
                    S(I,J,K)=-35.0*PI/2.0*COS(PI*X/2.0)*COS(3.0*PI*Y/2.0)&
                            *COS(5.0*PI*Z/2.0)
                END DO
            END DO
        END DO
        !$OMP END PARALLEL DO
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````            
        ! GAUSS-SEIDEL ITERATION
        PRINT *, 'PARALLEL START'
        T1=OMP_GET_WTIME()
      
        ITER=0
        DUMAX=1.0D0 ! UPDATE DIFFERENCE
        DO WHILE(ITER <= ITERMAX .AND. DUMAX >= TOL)
            ITER=ITER+1
            DUMAX=0.0D0
            !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(T_OLD, K, I, J, DUMAX)
            !$OMP DO REDUCTION(MAX:DUMAX)
            DO K=2,N-1
                DO I=2, N-1
                    DO J=2, N-1
                        T_OLD=T(I,J,K)
                        T(I,J,K)=1.0/6.0*(T(I+1,J,K)+T(I-1,J,K)+T(I,J-1,K)+T(I,J+1,K) &
                                    +T(I,J,K+1)+T(I,J,K-1) &
                                    -DX**2*S(I,J,K))
                        DUMAX=MAX(DUMAX, ABS(T_OLD-T(I,J,K)))
                    END DO
                END DO
            END DO
            !$OMP END DO
           !$OMP END PARALLEL
        END DO
        
        T2=OMP_GET_WTIME()

    END PROGRAM GAUSS_MP
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Does the solver converge without OpenMP? Or at least with OpenMP but with just one thread? Which exact results are you getting? Which equation are you even solving?

Comment: If it does not converge even with one thread, then forget OpenMP for this moment and just debug your serial program. Do not complicate it even more with OpenMP for no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gauss-Seidel is a sequential algorithm that cannot be parallelized easily.   If you take a look at the update of the `T` array, you'll see that you're reading values from other threads that may or may not have been updated when the current thread tries to process them.  That a typical race condition.

You have basically two options:

- use loop skewing to "turn" the loop nest by 45 degrees and use a wave front to go through the grid.  That way updated cells will be available when the current threads wants to read the updated value.
- use the OpenMP 4.5 feature 'ordered depend` to express the data dependency in your code and let the OpenMP compiler add the proper synchronization to avoid the race condition.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But what do you mean "turn" the loop nest by 45 degrees? Do you have any example? Thank you!

Comment: @ShiqiHe  Gauss Seidel can be parallelized almost trivially in the Red-Black modification. http://www.numa.uni-linz.ac.at/Staff/haase/parvor_e/node88.html  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719259/red-black-gauss-seidel-and-openmp That is probably meant by those 45 degrees. BTW, you really should include the info I requested, it really makes the question much better.

Comment: Red-Black Gauss-Seidel is NOT the original Gauss-Seidel algorithm. It has different properties. Re 45 degrees: please search for "loop skewing" and "wave front parallelization".

Comment: I DO know the Red-Black method is not the same (having used it and implemented it quite a few times before, although I mainly use direct solvers in production). It would really have nicer of you to give some more specific pointers rather than just "google it".

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify how the approach using `ordered` and `depend` mentioned by @Michael Klemm works, consider the following example of a parallel Gauss-Seidel solver which solves a Poisson problem in 3D.

```
SUBROUTINE gauss_seidel_par(u,f,N,itermax)
   REAL(dp), DIMENSION(:,:,:), INTENT(INOUT) :: u
   REAL(dp), DIMENSION(:,:,:), INTENT(IN) :: f
   INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: N, itermax
   INTEGER :: i, j, k, l
   REAL(dp) :: factor1, factor2
   factor1 = 1.0_dp/6.0_dp              ! Coefficient of u(i,j,k)
   factor2 = (2.0_dp/REAL(N+1.0_dp))**2 ! Delta^2
   !$omp parallel
   DO l = 1,itermax                     ! run until maximum number of iterations is reached
   !$omp do schedule(static,1) ordered(2)
   DO k = 2,N-1
     DO j = 2,N-1
       !$omp ordered depend(sink: k-1,j) depend(sink: k,j-1)
       DO i = 2,N-1
         u(i,j,k) = factor1*(u(i+1,j,k)+u(i,j+1,k)+u(i,j,k+1)+u(i-1,j,k)+u(i,j-1,k)+u(i,j,k-1) + factor2*f(i,j,k))
       ENDDO
       !$omp ordered depend(source)
     ENDDO
   ENDDO
   ENDDO
   !$omp end parallel
   END SUBROUTINE gauss_seidel_par
```

The `ordered` clause states that the loops should be passed in order, i.e. 1,2,3.... instead of a random order. The `depend` clause then specifies which updated values the scheme depends on, in this case, the points on the stencil that have already been passed.

Comment: This was already mentioned by Michael Klemm. What is the performance penalty?