# How to implement a scalable 3D Poisson red/black solver using OpenMP

Tags: performance, openmp

I want to write an OpenMP red/black SOR solver for the 3D Poisson equation (CFD), and I found some discussions talking about the 1D case (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719259/red-black-gauss-seidel-and-openmp)) but I wasn't able to find references solving the 3D case (there are CUDA references, but not for OpenMP).

It's basically a 3D convolution that accesses 6 neighbour cells for each cell it relaxes, so, it's very little math computation but a lot of memory access (and cache-unfriendly because you have 2 neighbours in the X axis, 2 in the Y axis, and 2 in the Z axis). Then you just have a few additions/mults with them, but I'm afraid the big cost here are these memory accesses in the 3 axes.

So I'm afraid this one is going to be very hard to achieve an efficient scale factor with OpenMP, and before trying blindly, I'd like to start writing it in a way that makes sense.

Yes, I thought that maybe I could decompose the memory in more "cache-friendly sub-cubes", but... is that complex transformation really worth it? I mean: Can I expect an almost perfect parallel scale factor from these "cache-friendly cubes"? I foresee quite a complex transformation of indexes for arranging the memory in these alternative way, so I'd do it only if I can expect good performance from it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that it is a bit hard to give a precise answer to this question without information about the target hardware (eg. processor speed, cache size, memory, etc.) and the software parameters (eg. data size).

> I could decompose the memory in more "cache-friendly sub-cubes", but... is that complex transformation really worth it?

If speed is a critical point, it definitively worth it. RAM accesses are very costly compared to cache accesses. Actually, the biggest problem is few threads will often quickly saturate the RAM while it should be much better with blocks as long as they **fit in the CPU cache**. This is especially true with the cache that are not shared (generally the L1/L2 cache on x86-64 mainstream processors).

There are many methods to do so. One famous solution is to use [*z-tiles*](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/efficient-use-of-tiling.html) or more generally *cache-oblivious stencil algorithms*. **Trapezoidal decompositions** are one of the most important method to use if the target stencils are computed iteratively in a loop. These algorithms are pretty complex to implement, but there are several **tools/frameworks** to do such stencils both efficiently and quite easily (see [Pochoir](http://supertech.csail.mit.edu/papers/pochoir_spaa11.pdf) for example, which reports very good speed-up compared to naive implementations).

> Can I expect an almost perfect parallel scale factor from these "cache-friendly cubes"?

Probably not. At least, not with only "cache-friendly cubes", and not on mainstream server processors with many cores and a quite *small RAM throughput*. That being said, using all the above combined methods can greatly help to improve both performance and scalability (especially the cache optimization in the time dimension). Assuming data can entirely fit in CPU caches, it may scale pretty well, if not perfect, regarding the target hardware (some processors like the recent AMD one can have huge and fast NUMA-based L3 caches, and some machines like IBM ones can have a quite big RAM throughput).